# Issue SQL join query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am getting issues with the below `SQL` query, unable to fetch the desired result

```
SELECT
    C.Department__c
   ,C.Email
   ,R.AcctID__c
   ,C.ContactID__c
   ,R.TransactionDueDate
   ,R.PubNbr__c
FROM  RenewalNotificationProgramDE R
LEFT JOIN ContactNewDE C  
    ON R.AcctID__c = C.AcctID__c
```

The idea is to join all the `AccountID(AcctID__c)` in `RenewalNotificationProgramDE` table to the corresponding contacts in `ContactNewDE` table. `AccountID` is the foreign key in the `ContactNewDE` table. I am usig Innerjoin in my query as I want all `AccountID` to map with their corresponding contacts in `ContactNewDE`.

Comment: you're not using inner join in that query. could you post some sample data and the expected output

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace LEFT JOIN by INNER JOIN to get all AccountID with their corresponding contacts :-

Use below query :-

```
SELECT
C.Department__c
,C.Email
,R.AcctID__c
,C.ContactID__c
,R.TransactionDueDate
,R.PubNbr__c
FROM  RenewalNotificationProgramDE R
INNER JOIN ContactNewDE C  
ON R.AcctID__c = C.AcctID__c
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used LEFT JOIN in your query, which you need to change it to INNER JOIN. I think you would better to notice the below notes about differences between left and inner joins:

- INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in **BOTH**
  tables
- LEFT JOIN: Return **all rows from the left table**, and **the
  matched rows from the right table**